# is there a vuelidate notSameAs validator

Tags: vuejs2, vuelidate

I came accross this issue about a simple password change form, in which I want to make sure that the new password is different from the old

I've tried implementing it directly following the [documentation](https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/#sub-custom-validators) :

```
import { ref, withParams } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
export const differsFrom = equalTo => withParams(
  {type: 'differsFrom', eq: equalTo},
  function (value, parentVm) {
    return value !== ref(equalTo, this, parentVm)
  }
)
```

Now, importing the proper items from vuelidate is not as easy as the documentation states it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `not`:

```
import { sameAs, not } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      password: '',
      oldPassword: ''
    }
  },
  validations: {
    password: {
      not(sameAs('oldPassword'))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `not` validator did not exist in vuelidate at the time of the question. Thanks for the update !

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

`withParams` is not a function there, have to import it like this:

```
import { withParams } from 'vuelidate/lib/params'
```

I could not find how to import `ref` properly... It kept saying that it was not a function.

Now, an implementation of a `not` validator works just as well:

```
import { withParams } from 'vuelidate/lib/params'
export const not = validator => {
  return withParams({type: 'not'}, (...args) => !validator(...args))
}
```